# Can I divorce my husband due to lack of trust?

Tags: talaq, husband-wife

He chats and speaks on the phone with other women but does not speak to me. He denies that he does this by claiming that he fears Allah and would never commit adultery. But, I clearly see the messages proving it when I go through his phone.

He also believes it is normal to be around non-Mahram women without marriage. Is this a ground for divorce in Islam?

Comment: It seems to me that you have enough grounds for divorce. But, you should speak to an Imam and ask him to advise you in your situation.

Comment: Use meaningful and related tags and in readable English. Also take our [tour] and check the  [help] for further information on our site and model.

Comment: You may want to advise your husband not to do that and refer him to your local Imam or some elderly from family. Situations like these can be controlled if dealt carefully.